# 'Terminated due to timeout'

Tags: python, python-3.x, bitwise-operators

Why this code is showing '**Terminated due to timeout**' on Hackerrank ?

I'm trying to do a task at **Day 29: Bitwise AND** in '**30 days of code**' on **Hackerrank**. Here is the task:

> **Task**
>
> *Given set **S** = {1,2,3,...**N**}. Find two integers, **A** and **B** (where **A** < **B**),  from set **S** such that the value of **A & B** is the maximum possible and  also less than a given integer, **K**. In this case, **&** represents the  bitwise AND operator.*
>
> **Input Format**
>
> *The first line contains an integer, **T**, the number of test cases. Each of the **T** subsequent lines defines a test case as **2**
>   space-separated integers, **N** and **K**, respectively.*
>
> **Constraints**
>
> *1 <= **T** <= 10^3
>
>    2 <= **N** <= 10^3
>
>     2 <= **K** <= **N***
>
> **Output Format**
>
> *For each test case, print the maximum possible value of **A & B** on a new  line.*
>
> **Sample Input**
>
> *3*
>
> *5 2*
>
> *8 5*
>
> *2 2*
>
> **Sample Output**
>
> *1*
>
> *4*
>
> *0*
>
> **Explanation**
>
> ***N*** = 5, **K** = 2, **S** = {1,2,3,4,5}
>
> *All possible values of and are:*
>
> **1**. ***A*** = 1, **B** = 2; **A & B** = 0
>   **2**. ***A*** = 1, **B** = 3; **A & B** = 1
>   **3**. ***A*** = 1, **B** = 4; **A & B** = 0
>   **4**. ***A*** = 1, **B** = 5; **A & B** = 1
>   **5**. ***A*** = 2, **B** = 3; **A & B** = 2
>   **6**. ***A*** = 2, **B** = 4; **A & B** = 0
>   **7**. ***A*** = 2, **B** = 5; **A & B** = 0
>   **8**. ***A*** = 3, **B** = 4; **A & B** = 0
>   **9**. ***A*** = 3, **B** = 5; **A & B** = 1
>   **10**. ***A*** = 4, **B** = 5; **A & B** = 4
>
> *The maximum possible value of **A&B** that is also < (**K** = 2) is 1, so we print 1 on a new line.*

Here is my code:

```
import math 
import os 
import random 
import re 
import sys

if __name__ == '__main__': 

t = int(sys.stdin.readline()) 

for t_itr in range(t): 

  nk = sys.stdin.readline().split()

  n = int(nk[0]) 

  k = int(nk[1]) 

  lst1 = [(a, b) for a in range(1, n + 1) for b in range(a + 1, n + 1)]

  lst2 = [ a & b for (a,b) in lst1 if a & b < k] 

print(max(lst2))
```

This task has total 6 test cases, in test case 1 and 2, my code is True, but in 4 next test cases, it raise: '**Terminated due to timeout**'.

Can you explain for me what am I wrong ? And what can I do to finish all the test cases? Thanks for helping me !

Comment: your code is not as optimal as it could be ... i would head over to codereview.stackexchange they are probably better at optimizing this stuff ... for starters i think if list1 was a generator that might be slightly faster ... you can probably also eliminate large chunks of the test set by some methods

Comment: ok, whatever u can help me is ok!

Comment: oh, it's called for me

Comment: So what can I do ?

Comment: Pen, paper, brains. Use them before writing any code. What does it mean for A&B to be max? When does it happen? What are a few examples for small N and K? Is there a pattern?

Comment: Actually, you may be able to solve this without any searching at all.  You just need to do a careful case analysis to see what form the desired result has.  So there may be an O(1) solution.

Comment: you True. I'm trying...

Comment: You sure are importing a lot of overhead you're not using. Perhaps you should start by addressing that. Seems to me you only need to import `sys` and nothing else.

Comment: oh, u True, but i don't understand why Hackerrank prodvides it for me ? I should delete it.

Comment: Oh, I was wondering about the unnecessary imports as well.  I didn't realize it came from some fixed template they provided.

Comment: A question that should be interesting: since you want A&B to be max and less that K, when is the max *not* equal to K-1? There aren't many cases, and they relate to the binary representation of K and N. Is the max always K-2 when it happens?

Comment: can u explain it more specifically ? I'm not sure I understand, I'm just beginner.

Comment: please explain more specifically, I'm just beginner

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The max of (something) such that (something) is less than K should be K-1. Unless it's not possible for some reason.

---

So let's have a look:

```
for n in range(2, 256):
    for k in range(2, n + 1):
        m = max(a & b for a in range(1, n + 1) for b in range(a + 1, n + 1) if a & b < k)
        t = "*" if m == k - 1 else " "
        print("{:s} {:3d} {:3d} {:3d} {:08b} {:08b} {:08b} {:3d} {:3d}".format(t, n, k, m, n, k, m, n - k, k - m))
```

Sample output:

```
    N   K   M     N        K        M    N-K K-M
----------------------------------------------
    2   2   0 00000010 00000010 00000000   0   2
*   3   2   1 00000011 00000010 00000001   1   1
*   3   3   2 00000011 00000011 00000010   0   1
*   4   2   1 00000100 00000010 00000001   2   1
*   4   3   2 00000100 00000011 00000010   1   1
    4   4   2 00000100 00000100 00000010   0   2
*   5   2   1 00000101 00000010 00000001   3   1
*   5   3   2 00000101 00000011 00000010   2   1
    5   4   2 00000101 00000100 00000010   1   2
*   5   5   4 00000101 00000101 00000100   0   1
*   6   2   1 00000110 00000010 00000001   4   1
*   6   3   2 00000110 00000011 00000010   3   1
    6   4   2 00000110 00000100 00000010   2   2
*   6   5   4 00000110 00000101 00000100   1   1
    6   6   4 00000110 00000110 00000100   0   2
*   7   2   1 00000111 00000010 00000001   5   1
*   7   3   2 00000111 00000011 00000010   4   1
*   7   4   3 00000111 00000100 00000011   3   1
*   7   5   4 00000111 00000101 00000100   2   1
*   7   6   5 00000111 00000110 00000101   1   1
*   7   7   6 00000111 00000111 00000110   0   1
*   8   2   1 00001000 00000010 00000001   6   1
*   8   3   2 00001000 00000011 00000010   5   1
*   8   4   3 00001000 00000100 00000011   4   1
*   8   5   4 00001000 00000101 00000100   3   1
*   8   6   5 00001000 00000110 00000101   2   1
*   8   7   6 00001000 00000111 00000110   1   1
    8   8   6 00001000 00001000 00000110   0   2
*   9   2   1 00001001 00000010 00000001   7   1
*   9   3   2 00001001 00000011 00000010   6   1
*   9   4   3 00001001 00000100 00000011   5   1
*   9   5   4 00001001 00000101 00000100   4   1
*   9   6   5 00001001 00000110 00000101   3   1
*   9   7   6 00001001 00000111 00000110   2   1
    9   8   6 00001001 00001000 00000110   1   2
*   9   9   8 00001001 00001001 00001000   0   1
```

Apparently, the max is often K-1 (starred rows), so it may be easier to find out when it's not K-1. Also, the max seems to be either K-1 or K-2.

---

Another test, showing only when the max is not K-1. This time we sort by K first, then N.

```
for k in range(2, 256):
    for n in range(k, 256):
        m = max(a & b for a in range(1, n + 1) for b in range(a + 1, n + 1) if a & b < k)
        if m != k - 1:
            print("{:3d} {:3d} {:3d} {:08b} {:08b} {:08b} {:3d} {:3d}".format(n, k, m, n, k, m, n - k, k - m))
```

And a sample from the output follows.

```
  N   K   M     N        K        M    N-K K-M
----------------------------------------------
  2   2   0 00000010 00000010 00000000   0   2
----------------------------------------------
  4   4   2 00000100 00000100 00000010   0   2
  5   4   2 00000101 00000100 00000010   1   2
  6   4   2 00000110 00000100 00000010   2   2
----------------------------------------------
  6   6   4 00000110 00000110 00000100   0   2
----------------------------------------------
  8   8   6 00001000 00001000 00000110   0   2
  9   8   6 00001001 00001000 00000110   1   2
 10   8   6 00001010 00001000 00000110   2   2
 11   8   6 00001011 00001000 00000110   3   2
 12   8   6 00001100 00001000 00000110   4   2
 13   8   6 00001101 00001000 00000110   5   2
 14   8   6 00001110 00001000 00000110   6   2
----------------------------------------------
 10  10   8 00001010 00001010 00001000   0   2
----------------------------------------------
 12  12  10 00001100 00001100 00001010   0   2
 13  12  10 00001101 00001100 00001010   1   2
 14  12  10 00001110 00001100 00001010   2   2
----------------------------------------------
 14  14  12 00001110 00001110 00001100   0   2
----------------------------------------------
 16  16  14 00010000 00010000 00001110   0   2
 17  16  14 00010001 00010000 00001110   1   2
 18  16  14 00010010 00010000 00001110   2   2
 19  16  14 00010011 00010000 00001110   3   2
 20  16  14 00010100 00010000 00001110   4   2
 21  16  14 00010101 00010000 00001110   5   2
 22  16  14 00010110 00010000 00001110   6   2
 23  16  14 00010111 00010000 00001110   7   2
 24  16  14 00011000 00010000 00001110   8   2
 25  16  14 00011001 00010000 00001110   9   2
 26  16  14 00011010 00010000 00001110  10   2
 27  16  14 00011011 00010000 00001110  11   2
 28  16  14 00011100 00010000 00001110  12   2
 29  16  14 00011101 00010000 00001110  13   2
 30  16  14 00011110 00010000 00001110  14   2
----------------------------------------------
 18  18  16 00010010 00010010 00010000   0   2
----------------------------------------------
```

So when the max is not K-1, it seems to always be K-2, and K must be even.
Consider `K=2**p` with p>0, to simplify (that is, forget the higher bits of K, for even K). The "natural" max should be K-1, that is `2**p-1`.

**Example:**

In binary, for K=1000, the natural max would be 111. But it can't happen if all the values we have at hand for A and B are less than K: the max for B would be 111, but then A must be smaller, so at least one bit will be lost. The max will then be 110, that is K-2.

This problem occurs when N is not much larger than 1000: if it is large enough, then we have enough values of A and B to get A&B=111. Specifically, if N is at least 1111, then with A=111 and B=1111, we are done.

When K is not a power of two, it's only slightly more complicated.

Now, you should have all necessary bits to finish.

A final check.

```
def p2(k):
    p = 1
    while k % (2 * p) == 0:
        p *= 2
    return p

count1 = count2 = 0
for k in range(2, 256):
    print("-" * 60)
    for n in range(k, 256):
        m = max(a & b for a in range(1, n + 1) for b in range(a + 1, n + 1) if a & b < k)
        t1 = "*" if m == k - 1 else " "

        if k % 2 == 0:
            p = p2(k)
            t2 = "*" if n <= k + p - 2 and m == k - 2 else " "
        else:
            t2 = " "

        if t1 == t2:
            count1 += 1
        else:
            count2 += 1

        print("{:s} {:s} {:3d} {:3d} {:3d} {:08b} {:08b} {:08b} {:3d} {:3d}".format(t1, t2, n, k, m, n, k, m, n - k, k - m))

print(count1, count2)
```

---

What to learn from this?

- Think about the algorithm: just throwing the obvious solution is usually not very good. Sometimes it's good enough, but usually not on Hacker Rank: they design tests to detect and reject solutions with poor complexity.
- Try with a pencil and paper. If it's too complicated, the closest to pencil and paper is printing some useful output using the poor algorithm, to try to understand how it could be improved.
- Read carefully the output, to find patterns. Improve the program to show more output to confirm your intuition.
- When there is something interesting, prove it (here the proof is far from complete, but you should see at least why it works).
- Check that you haven't missed another problem, by running another test.

---

Final note: to get the largest power of 2 that divives K, I used a loop. There is a much better way, that you will find by considering `K^(K-1)` (where `^` deontes exclusive-or, as in Python).
It's the kind of bit hackery that is often useful when optimizing code. You will find other examples [here](https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html) and [there](https://www.hackersdelight.org/).

---

Answer to the comment

- If K is odd, then since K<=N you can pick B=K, A=K-1, and then A&B=K-1, so you can always get K-1 if K is odd. And the max can't be greater than K-1, since it's one of the condition (max of A&B such that A&B

  If K is even and N is large enough, you may pick A=K-1, and K=K | (K ^ (K-1)), then pick B=K | (K ^ (K-1)). So A&B=K-1 is possible, and it can't be greater, so it's the max.

  In other cases (K is even and N is not large enough), then pick A=K-2, B=K-1 and you get A&B=K-2. It's not possible to obtain K-1 as I explained on an example in the answer, so K-2 is the max.

The condition can be simplified:

- First, K|(K^(K-1)) is always equal to K|(K-1) (in both cases we replace all the 0s on the LSB side with 1s).
- Second simplification: if K is odd, then K|K-1 is always equal to K and then N>=K|(K-1) always holds. Thus it's enough to check if N>=K|(K-1) in all cases, and never check if K is odd.

All in all:

If N>=K|(K-1), the max is K-1, otherwise it's K-2.

Comment: but why u know that ?

Comment: @NopeNope Why I know what?

Comment: why u know that max(a & b) is k-1, k-2, k-3 ?

Comment: i just test 1  case and see that the answers are equal to k-1